# Problemas al convertir un archivo con ffmpeg

Tags: java, ffmpeg

Intento convertir archivos WAV, FLAC y M4A a MP3 usando FFMPEG pero este no convierte todos los archivos del directorio que proporciono, solo convierte el primero porque se queda como que en un bucle infinito y para que termine de convertirlo tengo que forzar la finalización de la ejecución por lo que no logra convertir el siguiente archivo.

Adjunto el código a continuación:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class AudioConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputDirPath = "C:\\Users\\infoe\\OneDrive\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\AudioTagEdit\\test";
        String outputDirPath = "C:\\Users\\infoe\\OneDrive\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\AudioTagEdit";

        File inputDir = new File(inputDirPath);
        File[] files = inputDir.listFiles();
        if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("No hay archivos para convertir");
            return;
        }

        for (File inputFile : files) {
            String fileName = inputFile.getName();
            String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).toLowerCase();
            if (!extension.equals("wav") && !extension.equals("flac") && !extension.equals("m4a")) {
                //System.out.println("Archivo " + fileName + " no es compatible, se omite");
                continue;
            }

            String inputFilePath = inputFile.getAbsolutePath();
            String outputFilePath = getOutputFilePath(outputDirPath, fileName);
            String ffmpegCommand = String.format("cmd /c ffmpeg -i \"%s\" -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k \"%s\"", inputFilePath, outputFilePath);

            try {
                Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command(ffmpegCommand.split(" ")).start();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

                process.waitFor();
                System.out.println("Archivo " + fileName + " convertido con éxito");
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Proceso de conversión finalizado");
    }

    private static String getOutputFilePath(String outputDirPath, String inputFileName) {
        String outputFileName = inputFileName.substring(0, inputFileName.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".mp3";
        return outputDirPath + "\\" + outputFileName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema puede deberse a que el proceso que se crea para ejecutar FFMPEG no está siendo cerrado correctamente después de que termina la conversión del archivo actual. Es posible que el proceso siga en ejecución y esté impidiendo que se inicie el siguiente proceso para convertir el siguiente archivo en la lista.

Para solucionar este problema, asegúrate de cerrar el proceso correctamente después de que se complete la conversión de cada archivo. Puedes hacer esto llamando al método destroy() del objeto Process después de que se haya completado la conversión y se haya leído la salida del proceso.

Modifica tu código para cerrar el proceso de la siguiente manera:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command(ffmpegCommand.split(" ")).start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

int exitCode = process.waitFor();
if (exitCode == 0) {
    System.out.println("Archivo " + fileName + " convertido con éxito");
} else {
    System.out.println("Error al convertir el archivo " + fileName);
}
process.destroy();
```

En este ejemplo, después de que el proceso ha terminado, se comprueba el código de salida del proceso. Si el código de salida es cero, significa que el proceso se ha ejecutado correctamente y se muestra un mensaje de éxito. Si el código de salida no es cero, significa que se ha producido un error en el proceso y se muestra un mensaje de error.

Después de leer la salida del proceso y comprobar el código de salida, se llama al método destroy() del objeto Process para cerrar el proceso. Esto asegura que el proceso no siga en ejecución y libere los recursos asociados a él.

Comment: Gracias por tu aclaración, lo implementé pero sigo sin solucionar el error.